# SQL between subquery

Tags: sql, subquery

I would like to know how to run a SQL query that returns events that have a time that is in a valid segment.

For example, I have the two tables,

**Event**

```
event_id event_time
0        134
1        434
2        4300
```

**Segment**

```
segment_type segment_start_time segment_end_time
data1         100                130
data1         200                500
data1         700                8000
veto1         400                440
data2         150                450
data2         4000               5000
veto2         175                200
```

I want a query that would return

```
event_id event_time
1        434
2        4300
```

I was thinking something like

```
SELECT * 
FROM event
WHERE 
    event.event_time > (SELECT segment.segment_start_time FROM segment)
    AND 
    event.event_time < (SELECT segment.segment_end_time FROM segment)
```

But this just returns nothing. What am I doing wrong?

The next step I want to do is to find events times that are;

between a 'data' segment start time and end time AND
NOT between a 'veto' segment start time and end time

And finally, I actually have two type of data segments and veto segments. I want to return events that have times;

between a 'data1' segment start time and end time AND

between a 'data2' segment start time and end time AND

NOT between a 'veto1' segment start time and end time AND

NOT between a 'veto2' segment start time and end time

So from my example table above, the output I want would be

```
event_id event_time
2        4300
```

Comment: Will different segments ever overlap?  Will `events` or `segements` have more records?

Comment: What database and version are you using?

Comment: Segments could overlap, but only segments of different 'type' - see my  comment below. I am using SQlite 3.7.13

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm going to assume that you will normally have more entries in the event table than in the segment table.

This allow the pseduo-code to be "for every segment, check which events are valid".  This allows range-seeks on the event table.

```
SELECT
  event.event_id, event.event_time
FROM
  segment
INNER JOIN
  event
    ON  event.event_time >= segment.segment_start_time
    AND event.event_time <  segment.segment_end_time
GROUP BY
  event.event_id, event.event_time
```

The `GROUP BY` is only needed if different entries in `segment` can overlap.

The alternative approach is with the pseudo-code "for each event, check if any segments overlap it".

Doing so, however, will not allow a range seek *(see my comment on @MarkByers answer)*.

**EDIT** Following edit to question...

As far as I understand the changes, an event should only be returned if...

- The event time is within *at least* (one data1 segment AND also one data2 segment)
- The event time is not within (any veto1 segments OR any veto2 segments)

```
SELECT
  event.event_id, event.event_time
FROM
  segment
INNER JOIN
  event
    ON  event.event_time >= segment.segment_start_time
    AND event.event_time <  segment.segment_end_time
GROUP BY
  event.event_id, event.event_time
HAVING
      0 = SUM(CASE WHEN segment_type = 'veto1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
  AND 0 = SUM(CASE WHEN segment_type = 'veto2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
  AND 1 = SUM(CASE WHEN segment_type = 'data1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
  AND 1 = SUM(CASE WHEN segment_type = 'data2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

Comment: Thanks @Dems. This seems to work. Yes, there are segments that can overlap. But to be more accurate, the segment table has four distinct kinds of segments; data1 and data2, veto1 and veto2. I actually want to list events that have times that are in ((data1 - veto1) intersection (data2 - veto1)).

Comment: @ShaunH - I'm not sure what you mean by `((data1 - veto1) intersection (data2 - veto1))`.  Please could you update your question with example data and desired output that demostrates the real scenario?

Comment: I have edited the question. Sorry if it sounds complicated, that is why I didn't state all of it initialy

Comment: @ShaunH - Added a `HAVING` clause as best I understand your example.

Comment: sorry but this didn't work. But the logic is wrong I think. The event time has to be in the _intersection_ of the two kinds of data segments (I.e it has be with a data1 segment and a data2 segment). I think I have solved this using query - see below.

Comment: @ShaunH - It seems to work for your example, see this link...  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/2c89f/1

Comment: @ShaunH - In this link I have added an extra event at time = 475.  This is ***not*** within any veto segment, it **is** within a data1 segment, but it is ***not*** within a data2 segment.  My understanding is that it should not be returned because it's not within any data2 segments.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/f964e/1

Comment: ok I see your point. I think it didn't work because I didn't have the `GROUP BY` clause.

Answer (score 1):

Use `WHERE EXISTS` or a join.

```
SELECT event_id, event_time
FROM event
WHERE EXISTS
(
   SELECT *
   FROM segment
   WHERE event.event_time BETWEEN segment_start_time AND segment_end_time
)
```

Comment: Assuming an index of `segment(start, end)` this will mean that every `segment` with a `start` from `0` to `event.event_time` needs to have its `end` checked.  A half-cartesian product...

Answer (score 0):

If segments do not overlap, you can also use this (adapt with `TOP`  or `LIMIT` or whatever proprietary syntax if your DBMS has mot implemented the `OFFSET / FETCH` syntax):

```
SELECT
    event_id, event_time
FROM
    event AS e
WHERE 
    event_time <
    ( SELECT 
          s.segment_end_time
      FROM 
          segment AS s
      WHERE
          s.segment_start_time <= e.event_time
      ORDER BY 
          s.segment_start_time DESC
        OFFSET 1 ROWS
        FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY
    ) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the query I'm looking for, but I'm not 100% sure.

```
SELECT *
FROM event
WHERE EXISTS
(
   SELECT *
   FROM segment
   WHERE (event.time BETWEEN segment.start_time AND segment.end_time
                     AND segment.type IN ("data1", "data2"))
) AND EXISTS
(
   SELECT *
   FROM segment
   WHERE (event.time NOT BETWEEN segment.start_time AND segment.end_time 
                     AND segment.type ("veto1", "veto2"))
)
```

Comment: For the second `EXISTS`, it will return TRUE if the `event_time` is outside of *ANY* of the vetos.  So even if it collides with veto1, it's still outside of veto2 and so the overall condition is true, even though you want it to be false.  See this link...  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/f6957/1 *(Mine returns just event 2, yours returns events 1 and 2)*